# Parent and Child group values in the Same Column in the SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

[image]  I tried to achieve parent and child group values in the same column by looking at following URL: https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/ssrs-create-child-group-in-same-column-below-parent/
But this approach brings us empty row after every parent record just before child records. Need your help. Attached the image [image]
Thanks

Comment: can you show your layout / designer screen shot with the groups showing please?

Comment: Uploaded the design layout

Comment: Can you show some of your sample data as well please?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate null and blank values in your source data.

Comment: There are no null values in the dataset. When I try to add parent and group values in the same column I m getting empty row after each group as a first row